# Downloading, writing, converting and saving with imagemagick in python (corrupt images)

Tags: python, imagemagick, corrupt-data

Okay so I've been trying to solve this for about six hours now and it's just not happening.

I've got this function that grabs a bunch of image (GIF) files from a URL based on a timestamp (using the [Requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/). The images get saved to my desktop in a specific directory just fine. 
When I try to open that image, rename it and process it then everything breaks.

Here's the initial method that sets everything up:

```
def createImage():

    AB_CODES = ["WHK", "WHN", "WWW", "XBU", "XSM"]
    BASE_URL = "http://url_where_I_get_images_from"

    orig_dir = "originals/"
    new_dir = "processed/"

    # Add new image for each code
    for code in AB_CODES:
        radar_dir = BASE_URL + code
        url = requests.head(radar_dir)

        #parseUrl creates a valid timestamp corresponding to the latest image.
        timestamp = parseUrl(url)

        filename = timestamp + "_" + code + "_PRECIP_RAIN.gif"
        radar = BASE_URL + code + "/" + filename
        radar_img = requests.get(radar, timeout=30.000)

        # This is where the file from original source gets saved to my desktop, works.
        # Image gets saved in path/originals/img.gif
        if (radar_img.status_code == requests.codes.ok):
            image = radar_img.content
            filepath = os.path.join(orig_dir, filename)
            imgfile = open(filepath, "wb")
            imgfile.write(image)
            imgfile.close()

            # This is where I create a new image to be saved and worked on in
            # path/processed/new_img.gif
            image = radar_img.content
            filename = code + "_radar.gif"
            convpath = os.path.join(new_dir, filename)
            convimg = open(convpath, "wb")
            convimg.write(image)
            # This is the call to the function where I use imagemagick
            # which is not working
            image = processImage(convimg.name, "processed/XSM_radar_output.gif")
            convimg.close()
```

Here are the two methods that make up my processing function. Right now it's in more of a testing phase because it won't work.

```
def formatArg(arg):
    if arg.startswith("#") or " " in arg:
        return repr(arg)
    return arg

def processImage(input, output, verbose=True, shell=True):
    args = [
        "convert", input, 
        "-resize", "50x50", 
        output
    ]

    if verbose:
        print("Image: %s" % input)
        print(" ".join(formatArg(a) for a in args))
        print
    if os.path.exists(input):
        try:
            result = subprocess.check_call(args)
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
            result = False

        if result:
            print("%s : SUCCESS!" % output)
        else:
            print("%s : FAIL!" % output)
```

I've tried it without shell=true. The error message I get is that the image is corrupted:

```
Image: processed/XSM_radar.gif
convert processed/XSM_radar.gif -resize 50x50 processed/XSM_radar.gif
convert.im6: corrupt image `processed/XSM_radar.gif' @ error/gif.c/ReadGIFImage/1356.
convert.im6: no images defined `processed/XSM_radar_output.gif' @    error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3044.
processed/XSM_radar.gif : FAIL!
```

I don't understand why it's telling me that it's corrupted. I've run these exact same commands from the command line and it works just fine. 
(I have imported subprocess)

Comment: Maybe your python is running in a different directory and you need to put a full path on the filenames - just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

Someone helped me determine the error.

```
def processImage(input, output, verbose=True, shell=True):
    args = [
        "convert", input, 
        "-resize", "50x50", 
        output
    ]

if verbose:
    print("Image: %s" % input)
    print(" ".join(formatArg(a) for a in args))
    print
if os.path.exists(input):
    try:
        **result = subprocess.check_call(args)**
    **except subprocess.CalledProcessError:**
        **result = False**
    **if result:**
        print("%s : SUCCESS!" % output)
    else:
        print("%s : FAIL!" % output)
```

That section with the results should have been

```
result_code = subprocess.check_call(args)
```

and if it returned an error, result_code should have been set equal to 1.
So:

```
if result_code == 0:
    do stuff
```

Thank you for your attention!
Have a lovely day.